# Why there is not a community for embedded in stackexchange?

Tags: discussion

I think its not a place to ask this question but Why there is not a community for embedded in stack exchange. In stack exchange, every type of topics subjects & communities are available but not for embedded systems.

Comment: What kind of question about embedded systems you could not ask here?

Comment: define embedded

Answer (score 7):

A private beta for a new embedded SE was launched recently, but it will be shut down on Friday, August 14. The [explanation](http://meta.embedded.stackexchange.com/questions/69/closing-this-site-on-friday-august-14) for this is only available to members of the private beta group, so I will reproduce it here in full.

> About a year ago, we closed a [previous attempt](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50195/embedded-programming-and-design) at starting a site for
> Embededded Systems. At the time, the problem was there just wasn't
> enough activity to sustain a healthy site. Since then, we've put a lot
> of thought into [what we expect of sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) during the "beta" period.
> After considerable research (primarily by Ana and Pops, but with the
> input of the [entire team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do/99341)), we determined that there is no particular
> harm in allowing sites to continue operating with very little activity
> *as long as the community curates it's content.* As a result, we are far
> more reluctant to close tiny, but otherwise established communities.
>
> On the other hand, we are more reluctant than ever to launch sites
> before they've gathered momentum to carry them through the [inevitable
> post-launch lull](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141104/beyond-the-ask-and-answer-feature-is-there-a-way-to-motivate-semi-dormant-use). Users tend to drift away from sites that don't
> provide a constant supply of interesting questions and we've found it
> particularly difficult to recruit capable moderators for inactive
> sites. Slow starts in private beta invariably result in nearly static
> questions pages. Long-running betas also block new proposals that
> could be counted as duplicates.
>
> Currently, this site has [74 questions](http://embedded.stackexchange.com/questions) in [9 days](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70800/embedded-systems). While that would be a
> pretty good clip for a mature site, it's slow for a private beta:
>
> [image: Usage graph]
>
> Note that 20 questions on the first day is a little low and the rate
> drops from there. Inevitably, activity slows over the weekend, but the
> activity this week has barely rebounded at all.
>
> As with the last iteration, we don't have any problem with the content
> this site has produced. It's pretty clear that you all are very
> knowledgeable in this niche topic. There's just not enough activity to
> sustain a thriving Stack Exchange site. It's hard to know why this
> topic, which fits quite well with our core audience of developers,
> can't gain traction. Perhaps the problem is that [embedded systems
> questions](http://stackexchange.com/filters/171085/embedded-systems) already get asked around the network. According to [my
> estimation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271990/1438), the [embedded tag on Stack Overflow](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/225883/question-stats-by-tag?tag=%27embedded%27) gets good, timely
> answers:

```
TagName  N    median_views avg_score closed_rate avg_answers accepted_rate answer_rate median_tta
-------- ---- ------------ --------- ----------- ----------- ------------- ----------- ----------
embedded 4825 409          2.7       6.9         2.3         55.4          90.4        53
```

> Looking at [recent technology betas](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/8/technology?tab=beta) the most successful sites focus on
> well-defined communities such as elementary OS, CiviCRM, Vi and Vim,
> and Emacs users and developers. It could be that embedded systems
> professionals identify themselves primarily as programmers and
> engineers.
>
> Whatever the reason, this site will be **closing on Friday, August 14.**
> Please take a moment to identify exceptional content that could be
> migrated to an existing site so that it can be migrated. As always,
> all content (including migrated questions) will be available in the
> data dump released shortly after the site closes.
>
> Thank you for all your hard work proposing, defining, committing, and
> contributing to this beta.
>
> asked Aug 6 at 21:24
> [Jon Ericson ♦](http://meta.embedded.stackexchange.com/users/28/jon-ericson)

Several people objected to this decision on the grounds that nine days is not enough time to judge a site, especially during a popular vacation time for the Northern Hemisphere.  [Robert Cartaino ♦](http://meta.embedded.stackexchange.com/users/18/robert-cartaino) answered this in two comments. [First:](http://meta.embedded.stackexchange.com/questions/69/closing-this-site-on-friday-august-14#comment97_69)

> **To folks asking about the summer traffic levels** — I looked at similar sites (electronics, robotics, etc) and the traditional summer drop off is maybe 10% (if I'm being really generous). Our sites launch at all times of the year, so the numbers Jon cites above would have taken that into account anyway. But even if we accounted for the summer drop on an adjusted basis, the drop off is not enough to overcome the shortfall in participation. It just wouldn't have made a difference.

[Second](http://meta.embedded.stackexchange.com/questions/69/closing-this-site-on-friday-august-14#comment73_70), in response to a question about whether the shutdown could be averted:

> 120 high-quality questions by Tue, 8/11 would be cause to reconsider. But it would have to be sustainable, organic growth from an untapped audience; a few users pulling an all-nighter wouldn't help. I know it's tough to judge "success" by the numbers, but **the correlation between a slow start and sites that never gain traction is SO strong**, ignoring those hard-earned lessons is becoming increasingly irresponsible on our part. It's a good subject; every fiber of my being is screaming *"gawd, this site SHOULD work!"* But we've got to own up to it; we didn't pull it off this time.

Our own [Scott Seidman](http://meta.embedded.stackexchange.com/users/40/scott-seidman) has been through both attempts at launching an embedded systems SE, and offered [his opinion](http://meta.embedded.stackexchange.com/a/76/94):

> I have to add that the first launch seemed much more successful, and that the decision to close it then to help it build more momentum for a relaunch seems to have failed. I think the first go-around could have found a flame, but I don't think that this one can.
>
> Also, comparing to other successful tech stacks doesn't make sense unless you normalize to potential user base.

Scott also posted a [Meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263540/private-betas-rules-for-promotion-and-community-partnerships) where he discusses some of the problems he sees with the beta site launch process. It's visible to everyone, so I won't reproduce it here.

Answer (score 3):

The [Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50195/embedded-systems) explains what issues the site had.

Comment: [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) is the proposal site for Stack Exchange sites. It needs to pass through there before it is created.

Comment: There is a [2nd attempt at Embedded.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70800?phase=beta), which is in private beta at the moment.

Comment: @Nick apparently not much longer unless there's a change of mind: http://meta.embedded.stackexchange.com/questions/69/closing-this-site-on-friday-august-14 (personally I thought it had too much crossover with EE, SO and others)

Answer (score 3):

Obviously this is not a place to ask such questions. Embedded is purely electronics with programming so you can directly ask questions of your embedded in electronics community.

Comment: I disagree. Embedded is on (and over, on both sides) the boderline between electronics and programming. I have seen questions that are prefect for embedded being migrated from EE to SE.

Answer (score 0):

Emb. programming is "hardware" programming.... When you programm a MCU, a DSP, etc.. the level of abstraction is very low, therefore, it depends more on electronics design knownledge... The EE exchange can give support these questions.